# Calculating sun's azimuth angle for lat/long points in ArcMap or any other software

Tags: arcgis-desktop, solar-radiation

I am working on Solar project and I was just wondering if I could calculate sun azimuth angle for a location point shapefile in ArcGIS on any other software.
Are there any good detailed tutorials for Solar Radiation (toolset) in ArcGIS?